# Calling operations.get in gcp throws "field [name] has issue [invalid operation name]"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-apis-explorer

Recently I was trying to get the status of an operation calling operation.get on API explorer in GCP https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/operations/get

The request throws:
`field [name] has issue [invalid operation name]`

I tried the same request using node Lib for GCP and got the same result.

Operation name used is in format as below:
`operations/operation-1552901443197-5845b0ae4997f-496bcbdb-xxxxxx`

Did someone encounter this error before?

Comment: Seems that the operation that you are calling is not related to the [Resource Manager](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/). What resource your operation is tied to? I.e. the operation was made in Dataflow, App Engine, etc...

Comment: @JoanGrau The operation is from kind:"compute#operation"

Comment: You should use the Compute Engine API instead, I believe. Can you try [this API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/regionOperations/get) and check if it works? Note that this is for regional operations, if the operation is "global" you should use this [API instead](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/globalOperations/get). You can check if the operation is regional or global with the `gcloud compute operations list`, and checking if there is a region in the target field.

Comment: @JoanGrau I solved the issue using compute engine node Libs to get the operation status. I think that a more descriptive error message would help address the issue from the developers view. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to know that the issue has been resolved :). I have opened a Feature Request with the Google APIs team, in order to improve this error codes messages, I have added it as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is caused because the operation you are trying to fetch is from a different resource from the API that you are calling.

Most Cloud APIs have their own APIs, and each one performs its own operations under their own resource.

In this case you are trying to get your operation in the [Resource Manager API](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/operations/get), as a Resource Management resource, while it is from the Compute Engine resource, and [this API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/regionOperations/get) (or [this one](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/globalOperations/get) if the operation is global to your project) should be used instead.
Using this API instead would solve this issue.

I agree that the response message could be improved in order to point users to which is the actual issue, when facing issues like the one in this question.

That's why I have opened a feature request that you can see [in the following link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128895296). You can star it in order to give it more visibility and notifications on the updates made there, and add comments here if you have any additional information you might add to this improvement.

Comment: Thanks, I fell for that, too. :)